# Error handling in Ext.util.JSONP.request

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to connect to a server and when the server is down, the store should do something. All I need to know is how to catch that error/exception in Sencha touch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
                    url: "http://"+serverAdd+":"+ port+"/users/searchresults.json",
                    format: 'json',
                    callbackKey: 'callback',
                    params : searchCriteria,
                    callback: function(data) {

                                    store.getProxy().clear();
                                    store.data.clear();
                                    store.sync();
                    if(data.length < 10){
                    store.add({title: 'No Results found.'},
                          {company: 'Please try again !!'},
                          {posting_date: new Date()});
                    }
                                    else{store.add(data);}
                    },
                    failure: function ( result) { 
                    alert('Failed');
                                        console.log( 'Server not connected, please try again .. ');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for you, but someone on the Sencha forums modified the Ext.util.JSONP.request method to include setting the "onerror" attribute of the created  tag.  The post is [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153102-the-failure-event-of-Ext.util.JSONP.request-not-work).  Unfortunately, this method requires modifying the Sencha library code to implement.